# How to convert Map into javax.json.JsonObject?

Tags: java, lambda, javax.json

I can do so:

```
Map<String, String> mapA = ...;
Map<String, String> mapB = mapA.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Map.Entry::getValue
    ));
```

But when I'm trying to do this:

```
... mapA.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(JsonCollectors.toJsonObject(
        JsonObject.Entry::getKey,
        JsonObject.Entry::getValue
    ));
```

I get

> non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

for the `JsonObject.Entry::getKey, JsonObject.Entry::getValue` part.

Why's that?

Comment: What is your purpose for wanting to do this?

Comment: The JSON object will be part of an `application/json` HTTP response.

Comment: In what context? Every platform I know of (Spring, Micronaut, Dropwizard, Jersey) supports returning a regular object and does all of this automatically for you.

Comment: no framework, only java SE, com.sun.net.httpserver

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [add method of JsonObjectBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObjectBuilder.html#add-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```
JsonObjectBuilder builder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
mapA.forEach(builder::add);
JsonObject obj = builder.build();
```

Comment: That's the simplest solution I think.

Answer (score 2):

`javax.json.JsonObject` is child class of `Map<String,JsonValue>` so it has `putAll` method

```
void putAll(Map<? extends K,? extends V> m)
```

So you can just create `JsonObject` and add the `Map`

```
JsonObject object = Json.createObjectBuilder().build();
object.putAll(mapA);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it works, but the map has to be `<String, JsonValue>`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of javax.json use org.json

```
// Create a JSON object directly from your map
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject( srcmap );
// Convert it into string
String data = obj.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks, org.json is very neat, however javax.json is already used everywhere in the application, I have no way of replacing it.

Comment: you can try my answer @tom